# jhipster app fails to run - no obvious error

Tags: jhipster

I'm attempting to run a basic Jhipster application, from the below `.jdl` file.

I run the following commands:

1. `jhipster import-jdl sample.jdl`
2. `./mvnw`
3. After build completes I open my browser to http://127.0.1.1:8080/

From there I see the following error:

[image]

## JDL file

```
application {
  config {
    baseName sample,
    applicationType monolith,
    packageName com.sample.myapp,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    cacheProvider infinispan,
    buildTool maven,
    useSass true,
    testFrameworks [protractor]
  }
  entities *
}


entity Parent {
  symbol String unique
  description String
}

entity Child {
  location String unique
  comment String
  balance Long
  childType ChildType
}


enum ChildType {
    ALPHA,
    BETA
}


relationship OneToMany {    
    Parent to Child
}
```

## Logs

The log can be viewed at https://gist.github.com/magick93/72354c7f20c52180b0ffa53ae5b6b70b

## Versions

### Java

```
openjdk 12.0.2 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

### Node

- node v12.16.2
- npm 6.14.4

### Jhipster

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
```

### Additional

I've also tried

1. `npm install`
2. `npm start`
3. `jhipster import-jdl sample.jdl`
4. `./mvnw`

But still get the same error

Comment: What do you see in browser's console? Any error or failing API call?

Answer (score 0):

As it says, The problem is because of `npm install` is not run properly!

Try to run following commands in sequence.

```
npm install

npm start
```

and then try to import your .jdl or .jh file by,

```
jhipster import-jdl sample.jdl
```

then

```
./mvnw
```

Comment: Yes I had tried that, but still get the same error.

Comment: Cant say what it may be then!
As I got these error few times, and resolved it by this way.
And yes, I generally use Gradle with JHipster.
Anyways, at last you can try by restarting the system! it also works sometime! lol

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if that sounds stupid: But which browser are you using?

I have a similar behaviour with Firefox 75.0: When I start a vanilla jhipster generated application the error above is shown and I can see that there is no call to the backend. The JavaScript console just prints.

"TypeError: clazz.decorators is undefined"

When I use Chrome the application seems to work fine (again: plain vanilla jhipster application without any added entities)

Comment: Thanks @Ray, yes I"m also using FF. I havent tried Chrome. And yes I'm seeing the same console error.